# get partial text from result of document.querySelector()

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

[image]

I would like to extract the string "  (2017/01/15 12:27:59)", how do I locate it?
I tried "document.querySelector("div.aaa").innerText", but it gives the text in span.bbb and span.ccc too.
Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Don't post images, post text. Preferably post code as a runnable snippet. See [*How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you seem to be looking for is the text node after the span. The *nextSibling* property should suit, however I think some browsers only return element siblings, not other types of node. See [*MDN:Node.nextSibling*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling).

Anyway, try the following:

```js
var cccSpan = document.querySelector('.ccc');
var textNode = cccSpan.nextSibling;
console.log(textNode.data);
```

```css
.aaa {color: red;}
.bbb {color: blue;}
.ccc {color: green;}
```

```html
<div class="aaa">the div aaa
  <span class="bbb">span bbb</span>
  <span class="ccc">span ccc</span>
  text after ccc
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelector(".aaa").lastChild.textContent.trim()
```

`lastChild` will get textNodes as well as elementNodes.

Comment: That is essentially what the OP has already tried and said does not return the required result.

Comment: yeah, it still returns the text in the span.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested class selector:

```
document.querySelector(".aaa .ccc").innerHTML
```